# g++ option for showing all warnings except particular one

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, g++4.9

I am using GCC 4.9.2 on Linux.

I would like to enable display all warnings except a few. To enable all warnings, I have used `-Wall -Wextra` with `g++`.

But I would like not to have warnings for reorder i.e. I would like to set `-Wreorder` off.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Add `-Wno-reorder` after the other warning flags.

Answer (score 2):

Just read [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), as you would for any other such question:

> Each of these specific warning options also has a negative form beginning `-Wno-` to turn off warnings; for example, `-Wno-implicit`.

So, use `-Wno-reorder`.